# Python and matplotlib - Plotting and drawing images inside class methods result in figures that are "not responding"

Tags: python, image, numpy, matplotlib

I have created a class, ParRec, that reads data from Par/Rec-files (binary images -> numpy-arrays), and now I want to add additional methods to the class to increase functionality, such as a method createFigure(self, ind) that would draw an image of the 2D-image at ind in the 3D-stack of images.

However, this doesn't work no matter how I try, I only get empty figures which are "not responding". There is nothing wrong with the data per se, because when I saved the array to outside the python script and did the exact same thing as in the createFigure-method it did work. These are the relevant parts of the code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class ParRec():

    def __init__(self, filename, equalResolution = True):
    """
    This class is used to read and create a ParRec-object, which contains 
    arrays of parameters and the corresponding image matrix, in a similar way
    to the IDL-struct system previously implemented. 

    Additionally, the class has several methods that can be called later to
    simplify calculations, e.g. removePhaseImages and selectSlice.

    filename - full pathname to the Par/Rec-files, without .extension
    equalResolution - if set to false, ParRec-object collects parameters like
                      xres and yres in arrays, otherwise they are constants
                      and all images in the stack are assumed to be of equal 
                      dimensions.
    """       
    self.slice_number = 0      
    self.echo_number = 0
    self.dynamic_scan_number = 0
    self.cardiac_phase_number = 0
    self.image_type_mr = 0
    self.scanning_sequence = 0
    self.index_in_REC_file = 0                     # (in images)
    self.image_pixel_size = 0                      # (in bits) 
    self.scan_percentage = 0
    self.recon_resolution = 0                      # (x y)
    self.rescale_intercept = 0
    self.rescale_slope = 0
    self.scale_slope = 0
    self.window_center = 0
    self.window_width = 0
    self.image_angulation = 0                       # (ap,fh,rl in degrees)
    self.image_offcentre = 0                        # (3*float)
    self.slice_thickness = 0                        # (in mm)
    self.slice_gap = 0                              # (in mm)
    self.image_display_orientation = 0
    self.slice_orientation = 0                      # (TRA/SAG/COR) = (1/2/3)
    self.fmri_status_indication = 0
    self.image_type_ed_es = 0                       # (end diast/end syst)
    self.pixel_spacing = 0                          # (x y) (in mm)
    self.echo_time = 0
    self.dyn_scan_begin_time = 0
    self.trigger_time = 0
    self.diffusion_b_factor = 0
    self.number_of_averages = 0
    self.image_flip_angle = 0                       # (in degrees)
    self.cardiac_frequency = 0                      # (bpm)
    self.minimum_RR_interval = 0                    # (in ms)
    self.maximum_RR_interval = 0                    # (in ms)
    self.turbo_factor = 0                           # (0=no turbo)
    self.inversion_delay = 0                        # (in ms)
    self.diffusion_b_value_number = 0               # (imagekey!)
    self.gradient_orientation_number = 0            # (imagekey!)
    self.contrast_type = 0
    self.diffusion_anisotropy_type = 0
    self.diffusion = 0                              # (ap, fh, rl)
    self.label_type = None                          # (ASL) (imagekey!)

    self.xres = 0          
    self.yres = 0
    self.size = 0

    self.equalResolution = equalResolution

    # Read ParRec-files
    self.readPar(filename)
    self.readRec(filename)

    # Get number of slices, dynamics, information about phase images etc.        
    self.getAdditionalData() 


    def readPar(self,filename)
        ...

    def redRec(self,filename)
        ...
        self.matrix = ...

    def createFigure(self, ind):

        img = self.matrix[:,:,ind].astype(np.float32)
        fig = plt.figure()
        plt.imshow(img, cmap = plt.cm.gray)
        return fig



if __name__ == '__main__':
    filename = '...\filename'
    obj = ParRec(filename)
    fig = obj.createFigure(0)
    plt.show()
```

Can anybody explain what's going on? That is, why the image-drawing doesn't work when used as a class-method like this, and how to make it work?

EDIT: Inserted the **init** method, and managed to screw up the indentation a bit, but that is not a problem in the original code.

Best regards,
Mikael

Comment: show us the `__init__` function of class.

Comment: try to set `plt.ion()` at the beginning...

Comment: `plt.ion()`at the beginning didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: Are you missing `plt.show()` after creating the figure, i.e. after `fig = obj.createFigure(0)`?

Comment: **jmetz**, that's true, but adding it didn't help me :(

Comment: Which backend do you use?